# Ember did not match any routes in your application

Tags: ember.js

What's the best solution to handle 404 error from Ember App.

I tried to catch the error like this :

```
CL.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
actions: {
    error: function(error, transition) {

        debugger;
        if (error && error.status === 400) {
            // error substate and parent routes do not handle this error
            return this.transitionTo('modelNotFound');
        }

        // Return true to bubble this event to any parent route.
        return true;
    },
}
```

});

But it seems not to work... :(

Have you any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here : http://dinethmendis.com/blog/2013/7/30/handling-unsupported-urls-with-emberjs

I just added

```
this.route('missing', { path: '/*path' });
```

in the router map and then define the missing route.